# How do I catch an exception as described in the C++ standard, 17.6.4.10 [res.on.exception.handling]?

Tags: c++, exception, boost

**Short version:**  What is "an exception as described in the C++ standard, 17.6.4.10 [res.on.exception.handling]" and how do I catch one?

**Long version...**

I would like to catch the exceptions thrown from the version of [`boost::create_directories()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#create_directories) that does not take a `system::error_code` as an argument.  The [Boost Filesystem Error Reporting Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#Error-reporting) says that `create_directories()` reports errors either by...

a> throwing a `boost::filesystem_error` when a call by the implementation to an operating system or other underlying API results in an error that prevents the function from meeting its specifications, or...

b> throwing an exception as described in the C++ standard, 17.6.4.10 [res.on.exception.handling] when there is a failure to allocate storage.

The first case is obvious and I have handled that situation.  But I can't find any explanation of how to handle the second case.  Googling "exception as described in the C++ standard, 17.6.4.10 res.on.exception.handling" yields three articles (that could be a record for a non-zero search result), and none of them tell me how to handle such an exception.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what they mean is that they will (indirectly) throw `std::bad_alloc`.  You may not actually want to try to catch that though, as a program which has run out of memory may not be able to continue in any case.  Up to you though--I read this same documentation just the other day and that's the conclusion I came to.

Comment: So by "failure to allocate storage" they mean memory?  I thought it meant disk space (being a file system call).

Comment: I think they mean memory, yes.  Any file-related failure should result in (a descendant of) their custom exception class being thrown as described in the first case.  Confusing wording, true.

Answer (score 1):

The actual paragraph of the current C++11 standard regarding exception handling is §17.6.5.12.
But there is no helpful information on what a boos library may throw except if the have throw specifying paragraphs.

I think what you want is to catch a `std::exception` since the most likely case in terms of " throwing an exception [...] when there is a failure to allocate storage" is a `std::bad_alloc`  which derives from `std::exception`.

Answer (score 0):

Just came to the same question while reading `boost::filesystem` documentation. In n4296 draft of C++14 standard following declared:

> 17.6.5.12 Restrictions on exception handling
>
> 1. Any of the functions defined in the C++ standard library can report a failure by throwing an exception of a type described in its Throws: paragraph. An implementation may strengthen the exception specification for a non-virtual function by adding a non-throwing noexcept-specification.
> 2. A function may throw an object of a type not listed in its Throws clause if its type is derived from a type named in the Throws clause and would be caught by an exception handler for the base type.

This doesn't sound informative, thus the real answer needs to be found in boost sources, which are currently hosted on [Github](https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/blob/develop/src/operations.cpp). Actually, per implementation defined there the `boost::filesystem::filesystem_error` exception will be thrown if `ec` argument was not provided.

```
if (ec == 0)
  BOOST_FILESYSTEM_THROW(filesystem_error(
    "boost::filesystem::create_directories", parent, local_ec));
```